# '+' character not saving through CKEditor/PHP/MySQL/HTMLPurifier

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor, htmlpurifier

I am trying to get UTF-8 encoding working with CKEditor/PHP/MySQL/HTMLPurifier.

I have converted the character sets of the database tables/fields to utf8-unicode-ci.

I have set the following in the ckeditor config:

```
config.entities = true;
config.entities_latin = true;
config.entities_greek = true;
config.entitles_processNumerical = true;
```

And PHP is purifying the HTML with HTMLPurifier with the default settings.

I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing for trying to accept UTF-8, but characters such as α are working... but for some reason, any '+' in the text just simply disappears.

Any ideas?

Comment: + signs disappearing seems to indicate that you're somehow doing the URL encoding/decoding round trip, but you haven't given enough information for me to really tell. Do plus signs turn into spaces? Can you put in debugging statements? What does HTML Purifier see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had unnecessarily urlencoded the text before the post request, while jQuery/AJAX was already encoding it. Removed the javascript encode() and the PHP urldecode() and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the text is urlencoded before post request.

If you do not 'urlencode' the text then the '+' character will be treated as space. 
If you urlencode the text then the '+' character will look like: '%2B'.

Answer (score 0):

For CKEditor 3.x and greater and for php forms try this

```
include_once "ckeditor/ckeditor.php";
// The initial value to be displayed in the editor.
$initialValue = 'This is a test  - Αυτο ειναι ενα τεστ';
// Create class instance.
$CKEditor = new CKEditor();
// Path to CKEditor directory, ideally instead of relative dir, use an absolute path:
// If not set, CKEditor will try to detect the correct path.
$CKEditor->basePath = 'ckeditor/';
$CKEditor->config['height'] = 450;
$CKEditor->config['skin'] = 'kama';
**$CKEditor->config['entities_greek'] = false;**
$CKEditor->editor('MyEditor',$initialValue);
```

Manos The Greek